# jQuery not rebinding event to handler after unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#element', function(e){
     alert('test');
});

$(document).on('click', '#element_b', function(e){
     $(document).off('focusout','#element');
     /* do other stuff */
     $(document).on('focusout','#element',function(){});
});
```

On clicking on `#element_b`, the event bound to `#element` is supposed to get off and then back on but for some reason after it goes off, it doesn't return back on. How to get it back on?

Comment: The `.on()` call in the "click" handler binds an event handler that doesn't do anything. Also, why would you need to do that? What's in that "do other stuff" code that would require such a thing?

Comment: I want the original one written at top to return back to work because it has a long piece of code so I don't want to copy the whole code down there in the click handler. Is there a way to just "turn it back" on? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to "turn it off" in the first place? While that "click" handler is running, the other handler won't run anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to re-bind a handler, the handler function must be available for reference at the point it would be re-bound. To achieve that, just define the handler function with a name:

```
function focusOutHandler(e) {
  alert("test");
}

$(document).on("focusout", "#element", focusOutHandler);
```

Then you can also reference the function in your "click" handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#element_b', function(e){
     $(document).off('focusout','#element');
     /* do other stuff */
     $(document).on('focusout', '#element', focusOutHandler);
});
```

Now, that said, that operation really doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of your question. While the "click" handler code is running, the "focusout" code will not run anyway. Thus, removing the handler at the start of the code and then adding it back at the end won't have any noticeable effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally argue for a different approach so you can stop modifying the bindings.  Instead change your matcher so it is more restrictive.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#element:not(.restricted)', function(e){
    alert('test');
});
```

If you made the selector like this, all you would have to do to "toggle" it on or off is add/remove the `restricted` class to the element, or whatever more restrictive matcher you give the delegate.